# How to use Cache::remember with HttpSocket->post cakephp

Tags: php, caching, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, anonymous-function

I want to cache `HttpSocket->post` calling in CakePHP 2.

I'm calling the following code:

```
$content = Cache::remember($key, function () use ($rateUrl, $xml, $uid) {
    App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket(array('ssl_verify_peer' => false));
    return $HttpSocket->post($rateUrl, $xml->asXML(), array(
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
            'RestUid' => $uid,
        )
    ));
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

> The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "HttpSocketResponse" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

Do anybody know the way how to use the `HttpSocket` class in an anonymous function or call in CakePHP or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you have to

> [...] ensure that the class definition "HttpSocketResponse" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

The class definition for the serilaized object of type `HttpSocketResponse` isn't available when it has been deserialized, so things won't work. Either add a corresponding `App::uses` statement before invoking `Cache::remember()`, so that CakePHPs autoloader can load the required class definition

```
App::uses('HttpSocketResponse', 'Network/Http');

$content = Cache::remember(/* ... */);
```

or switch to using Composer, so that the required class can be autoloaded without any `App::uses()` calls. Alternatively it's also possible to use the `unserialize_callback_func` ini directive to define a callback that loads the required class definition.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Installation > Advanced Installation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html)**
- **[PHP Manual > Function Reference > unserialize](http://php.net/en/unserialize)**